# How do I stop a segue from going through programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is the code:

```
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: nil)

            print("User is signed in with Firebase.")
        }
    }
}
```

I have a segue, `loginSegue`, connected from the login button to the `homeViewController`. Within in the `if error` statement I would like to stop the segue from going through because the user has not signed in. The goal here is not allow the user to go forward if they get an error. Is there an "opposite" to the `performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)` ?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... you are already calling `.performSegue` ***only*** if the error is nil.

Comment: Your code **does not** perform the segue in the error case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Vadian it still does because the segue is there and automatically goes through.

Comment: @KoolKid - you cannot have a Segue connected to a button ***AND*** call it from an `@IBAction` connected to the button. Create your segue from the **view controller** instead of from the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , there is no "opposite" to performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?).

But the issue is not about this. I think you wired the segue from the login button and gave it an identifier. If you wire a segue from a button directly the button is always going to execute that segue. Doing some operations in the button's action does not effect.

You need to wire a segue from FirstVc to SecondVc (not from the button) and then give the segue an identifier. Then, from the button's action you can check if there is no error and call performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender:) passing your segue's identifier.

Comment: I was thinking this but didn't know how to do it. When I read your response I was like "OH!" I'm supposed drag from the top bar of the vc and not from the screen itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your button is connected to perform segue in storyboard. So your button has two actions - one from storyboard to perform segue and second in your code. Just remove the connection from storyboard and connect only UIViewControllers not with your button.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:,sender:)` method and return false if the login fails and you don't want to perform the segue. Here's an example

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String?, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if let ident = identifier {
        if ident == "YourIdentifier" {
            if loginSuccess != true {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I already solved the issue with the other answers but this would useful for my google sign in because the approach is different. In regular login `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error)` is used whereas in the google sign button I have `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`. Now with regular login I am working with a condition, as in if the user signs in, do this. But the GIDSignIn takes place in the appDelegate.

Comment: Is there a way to use performSegue in the appDelegate?

Comment: I just tried `self.window?.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "googleSegue", sender: nil)` in the AppDelegate but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should add the function that I've given in the view controller class that you're performing the segue on.

Comment: I know what you mean but the view controller does not directly deal with the Google sign in process.